# What are the objections to Pelosi's COVID-19 Bill?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, summary-request, nancy-pelosi

Subsequent to the Democrats blocking the Coronavirus Aid, Relief, and Economic Security (CARES) Act in the US Senate on Sunday, March 22nd, in a 47-47 vote that was split along party lines, Nancy Pelosi and House Democrats released their own counter-proposal titled the Take Responsibility for Workers and Families Act.

Given that the Democrat bill

> ...would prevent corporations from using taxpayer money for stock
>   buybacks, boost unemployment insurance, strengthen the child and
>   earned income tax credits and inject nearly $40 billion into schools
>   and universities to stabilize funding.

And also

> ...directs billions of
>   dollars in grant funding for states to carry out this year's election
>   through the Election Assistance Commission.

https://www.npr.org/2020/03/23/820155258/read-house-democrats-release-3rd-coronavirus-response-bill

what were the Republican objections to the counter-proposal?

Comment: [Related question about objections to CARES](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/51159/2130)

Comment: To clarify, are these actually Pelosi-supoorted? I thought she was telling Democrats *not* to vote selfishly.

Comment: The linked article mentions "Pelosi's move to release this bill could be a strategic effort to increase pressure on the Senate to reach a deal." This statement implies that she supports it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

House Republican Whip Steve Scalise has given a [press release](https://scalise.house.gov/media/press-releases/pelosis-wishlist-far-left-policies-completely-unrelated-coronavirus) which outlines the objections of Republicans to the bill, calling it a wishlist of "insane far-left policies". The objections in particular seem to relate to the amount of non-coronavirus related provisions within the bill. Republicans argue that these measures are unnecessary, and an abuse of the pressure currently on Congress to come up with a rescue package.

I won't reproduce the whole list of provisions that Scalise has picked out as objectionable, but they include environmental reform policies, an increase to the minimum wage, a law to force companies to disclose board of director diversity statistics, and a requirement that unions should have a seat on airline corporate boards. Many of these policies seem tangentially related, if at all, to the COVID-19 crisis.

These concerns have been echoed by other Republican groups, such as the Republican House Oversight Committee, who [tweeted](https://twitter.com/gopoversight/status/1242167210497445894):

> Speaker Pelosi's [#coronavirus](https://twitter.com/hashtag/coronavirus) bill includes:
>
> - Provisions for a federal takeover of elections
> - A climate change study on aviation
> - Intrusive corporate diversity reporting burdens
>
> Seriously? Now is the time to help struggling Americans, not play
>   swamp politics with virus aid.

USA Today has [published](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/opinion/2020/03/23/nancy-pelosi-has-packed-coronavirus-stimulus-liberal-wish-list-column/2903577001/) an opinion piece by James S. Robbins on the bill, which describes it as a "Christmas in March for liberal special interests". In particular, Robbins takes umbrage with the changes that would be made to elections:

> Perhaps the most troubling sections of the bill are under the rubric
>   ‘‘American Coronavirus/COVID–19 Election Safety and Security” or
>   ‘‘ACCESS” Act. This section would impose requirements on states for
>   early voting, voting by mail, required mailing of absentee ballots to
>   everyone, ballot harvesting (i.e., having third parties deliver
>   absentee ballots), online voter registration, same-day registration
>   and other practices which undermine confidence in the integrity of the
>   ballot. In these days of increasing threats to election security we
>   should be moving rapidly back to in-person paper ballots, but this
>   bill would be a radical step in the wrong direction.

Comment: I seem to remember something also about abortion law changes too.

Comment: @Owl The didn't want to change abortion law. But rather, it looks like republicans/democrats accused each other regarding abortion stuff not in the bill. But, according to https://www.snopes.com/news/2020/03/13/coronavirus-bill-abortion/, it looks like both side's claims were unfounded and it didn't really matter at all.

Comment: @TheNumberOne Okay, i see it was political point scoring on both sides.